# Obtener dependencias de una vista

Tags: mysql

Necesito obtener las dependencias vistas, es decir, que objetos de las base de datos necesitan ser creados antes de la vista en cuestión.

**Ejemplo:**

- Tablas
- Funciones
- Vistas (si depende de otra vista)

He intentado consultar la tabla **information_schema.views** pero no me da la información que necesito ya que me muestra sólo los siguientes campos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el campo **VIEW_DEFINITION** se encuentra el código de creación de la vista, el cual podría utilizar para analizarlo y extraer de alguna manera los objetos involucrados, pero realmente no se como hacerlo.

¿Existe alguna manera de encontrar las dependencias de las vistas en MySQL?

Comment: Me temo que MySQL no cuenta con esa funcionalidad. Hay una posibilidad que podría ser interesante, sería indicar en la columna `table_comment` de la vista una lista de las tablas que intervienen... pero el comando `CREATE VIEW ` no permite agregar comentarios. Con ciertos privilegios creo que sí se puede actualizar  ese campo. Actualmente, esa información sólo se encuentra en la columna `VIEW_DEFINITION`, se podría intentar sacar de allí los nombres de tabla, cosa harto difícil, dado que los comandos de creación de una vista pueden ser muy variopintos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este query te proporciona la información necesaria para tomar decisiones en este 
caso. Incluye esquema, vista, tabla y tipo de tabla (tabla o vista):

```
SELECT
  tab.TABLE_SCHEMA AS `esquema`,
  views.TABLE_NAME AS `vista`,
  tab.TABLE_NAME AS `tabla`,
  tab.TABLE_TYPE AS `tipo`
FROM
    information_schema.`TABLES` AS tab
    INNER JOIN information_schema.VIEWS AS views 
       ON views.VIEW_DEFINITION LIKE CONCAT('%`', tab.TABLE_NAME, '`%');
```

Comment: Funciona, pero lo que me preocupa es que una columna o cualquier otro objeto tenga el mismo nombre que una tabla. ¡Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!

Comment: Ya que en el proyecto en el cual estoy trabajando no va a ocurrir lo que comenté, me va a servir y mucho tu respuesta. Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Si, lamentablemente tiene el problema de poder confundir objetos con el mismo nombre pero me parece que en la definición de las vistas no puede ser de otra manera. De igual forma, que bien que te ha funcionado, si encuentras alguna forma de resolver ese problema no olvides compartirlo. ¡Saludos!